# How to Combine two array rand from two array data?

Tags: php

I m so confusing here with this problem, please help me to solve this.

I have 2 array data,

```
$one = array ("sinta","jojo","wawan","silvie");
$two = array ("eat","sleep","breakfast","sport");
```

I want to create a random output array from this 2 array, and i want this only pick 2 random array from each array data, so maybe the result would be like this :

```
$three = array ("sinta","silvie","breakfast","eat");
```

or

```
$three = array("jojo","silvie","eat","sleep");
```

and etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I don't like code only answers, but:

```
$three = array_merge(array_rand($one, 2), array_rand($two, 2));
shuffle($three);
```

You can read up on [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) in the linked manuals. This code picks 2 elements each from $one and $two at random, and then randomizes the order of the result.

Small warning: If you have string keys in your arrays they will be destroyed.

Comment: thanks for answering,yess i want the array output result is something like you said array ('sinta','eat','sleep','silvie'), no the numeric keys only

Comment: Then you could shuffle the result. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry! The last edit was completely my mistake. I even linked the manual for shuffle, but used it wrong. I edited the code another time, and now it should be fine. Sorry again.

Comment: i try your syntax,but the output is 1,

Comment: The output from `shuffle($three)` should be 1 (TRUE) if the shuffle function was successful.  What you need to do is print out the `$three` array after calling `shuffle`.

Comment: i have do that, but the result is 1

Comment: The output is just like this Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
)
my question is, how i can echo the value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$three[0] = $one[rand(0,3)];
$three[1] = $one[rand(0,3)];
$three[2] = $two[rand(0,3)];
$three[3] = $two[rand(0,3)];
```

thats the logic - I did not php for a while so check the syntax, please.
Now you have to assure that rand is not picking the same value twice or youhave to eat two breakfasts :-)

Comment: thank you for answering, but maybe this answer still not correct for me...